# Событие DragOver не приходит, при запуске программы под администратором

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-n-drop

Сделал GUI для серверной части системы, и начал было делать сам сервер, но при запуске приложения от имени администратора событие DragOver тупо не вызывается.
При обычном запуске все ОК.

Для чистоты эксперимента создал новое решение, где с окном из такого кода:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowDrop="True" >
    <Grid>
        <Label AllowDrop="True" Drop="UIElement_OnDrop" DragOver="UIElement_OnDragOver"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
private void UIElement_OnDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void UIElement_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Результат тот же самый.

Comment: <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowDrop="True" >
    <Grid>
        <Label AllowDrop="True" Drop="UIElement_OnDrop" DragOver="UIElement_OnDragOver"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Comment: Если вы хотите что-то добавить, используйте кнопку "править" под постом. Комментарии не предназначены для больших кусков кода.

Answer (score 5):

Это защита. UAC и всё такое. Если приложение, *из* которого производится перенос, имеет уровень доступа ниже, чем приложение, *в* которое переносится перенос, то операция запрещается на уровне операционной системы.

Соответственно, нельзя перенести что-либо из приложения, запущенного под юзером, в приложение, запущенное под админом. А вот наоборот — можно.

Код здесь совершенно не при чём. Вы можете запустить любое приложение, поддерживающее drag-n-drop, под админом, и убедиться, что на него нельзя ничего перенести из программ, запущенных не из-под админа.

См. [Q: Why Doesn’t Drag-and-Drop work when my Application is Running Elevated? – A: Mandatory Integrity Control and UIPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/patricka/q-why-doesnt-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi) для более подробного объяснения.

Если требуется перенос файлов, то существует костыль с [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilterex). См. [How to enable drag and drop between normal & UAC elevated privileges applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14091973).

Comment: Действительно, давно читал про изоляцию, но сейчас об этом не подумал.Спасибо за подробный ответ и ссылки.

Comment: Привет из могилы :)

Comment: @VladD Добро пожаловать на тусовку живых мертвецов. 

Comment: Я чаще всего захожу по нотификациям от Glorfindel :) У него есть заклинание вызывать духов из бездны.